# alignat problem

Tags: errors, amsmath, align

Whenever I try to use the `alignat` environment, it doesn't seem to work on my computer! I tried the following simple code (my file had `\usepackage{amsmath}`):

```
\begin{alignat}{3}  
    \min \quad x_1        & + 2x_2 & + 4x_3 &      &   & \\  
    \text{s.t.} \quad x_1 & + x_2  & + 3x_3 & =    & 5 & \\  
    2x_1                  & + x_2  & + 6x_3 & =    & 8 & \\  
    x_1                   &, x_2   &, x_3   & \geq & 0 & .  
\end{alignat}
```

On compilation, I get the following error:

```
    ! Missing # inserted in alignment preamble.  <to be read again>   
               \crcr l.114   \end{alignat}
```

Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: That code works for me. Does it work for you if you just use that in an otherwise empty document?

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while, and you probably fixed your problem by now. But since another question involving `alignat` (well, my answer involves it anyway) came up, and this question scores quite high for the [Google query `latex alignat`](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=latex+alignat&*), I wanted to make sure that there's more information here....

---

I'm not sure what you are trying to align. I'm assuming you want the x_i's aligned, in which case the correct solution would be

```
\begin{alignat}{3}
\min \quad x_1& {}+{}& 2x_2& {}+{}& 4x_3& \\
\text{s.t.} \quad x_1& {}+{}&x_2&{}+{} & 3x_3&=5\\
2x_1& {}+{}& x_2& {}+{}&6x_3& = 8\\
x_1&, &x_2&, &x_3& \geq 0 .
\end{alignat}
```

which produces:

[image]

while your code produces:

[image]

As you see, you need to put alignment characters **between** the columns to be aligned, not only inside the columns.

Comment: There is a lot of missing white space in your example. You should perhaps write `{}+{}` instead of `+`?

Comment: Explaining why the `{}+{}` are needed: (I think) LaTeX typesets the spaces around binary operators differently than it does around unitary ones. we would want `+r` to have less space between the two characters than `b+r`. And since each column in alignat is typeset separately, it doesn't "see" that the `+`'s are binary operators.

Answer (score 1):

Your code also compiles for me, and as [Lev suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1924/alignat-problem#1927) constructing a [minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) will really help to narrow down where your problem lies, but I was able to generate a similar error to what you have by incorrectly using the `tabular` environment inside the `alignat` environment.

For example,

```
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
  \begin{tabular}{||}
    test
  \end{tabular}
\end{alignat}
```

results in the error

```
! Missing # inserted in alignment preamble.
<to be read again> 
               \cr 
l.9 \end{alignat}
```

Since the `l.9` and `l.114` just refer to line numbers in the code, the main difference is that my error includes `\cr` where yours says `\crcr`.

I can solve my alignment preamble error by using at least one correct column alignment character in the `tabular` environment, for example by  switching to `\begin{tabular}{|c|}`.