# Multiple Tab stops in Math Split?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath

I am using mathmode with `split`. How can you use multiple tab stops. I want to span an equation across multiple lines, but then the last few I want to indent even more.

```
\[
\begin{split}

some& stuff here \\
    &some &more stuff here \\
          &even more stuff here

\end{split}
\]
```

Notice the 2nd tab stop and I want to look like it's shown with the tabs.

Comment: Does this post help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29612/aligning-polynomial-terms/29615#29615

Comment: @cmhuges not really as that uses align, but i found \qquad which is fine for me.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of what you'd like?

Comment: If you post an example of the kind of equation you'd like to typeset, I'm pretty sure people will come up with solutions that might work better for you than using `\qquad`. `\qquad` is not the same as a tab, as it just adds a fixed amount of space and doesn't ensure proper alignment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides the `alignat` environment that is able to provide tab stops as needed. Some overlap support may be required via [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools). It provides the mathematical equivalent of `\llap` and `\rlap`. Although it's also possible using a regular `align` with some `\phantom`s for spacing:

[image: alignat in amsmath]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}% Also loads amsmath

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  E &= \mathrlap{mc^2 - 2x^4 + abc} \\
    &\phantom{{}={}} ayz - 2 && + 3 + 2 \\
    &                        && - b + \operatorname{ord}(xyz - ijk)
\end{alignat*}

\begin{align*}
  E &= mc^2 - 2x^4 + abc \\
    &\phantom{{}={}} ayz - 2 + 3 + 2 \\
    &\phantom{{}= ayz - 2} - b + \operatorname{ord}(xyz-ijk)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does rlap do?, also i see phantom a lot, what does that do? Is there no way to do this with split? Thanks!

Comment: `\rlap{<stuff>}` is equivalent to `\makebox[0pt][l]{<stuff>}` (providing a right overlap), while `\llap{<stuff>}` does the same for a right overlap (`\makebox[0pt][r]{<stuff>}`). `\phantom{<stuff>}` prints a box of width & height of `<stuff>` without actually typesetting `<stuff>`. Similarly, `\hphantom{<stuff>}` and `\vphantom{<stuff>}` provides horizontal/vertical-only spacing of `<stuff>` without actually typesetting anything. The `split` environment only allows a single alignment character `&`, so you'd have to use spacing (`\quad` or otherwise).

Answer (score 4):

The `nath` package provides `\wall` and `\return` to align at arbitrary locations. Here is Werner's example coded using nath syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  E \wall = m c^2 - 2x^2 + abca \\
          \quad ayz-2 \wall{} +3+2 \\
              {} - b + `ord (xyz-ijk) 
      \return \return
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Why is the first `\wall` before the `=`? If it was after the `=`, the `\quad` on the next line would not be required, which is better IMO.