# Aligning polynomials rightshifted by x

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, pdftex

I am trying to align some generating functions, to give a visual indication of how they represent recurrences. When I try to do this the natural-seeming way with `aligned`, it puts an obnoxiously large space after the constant term, and also leaves out some spacing around the plus signs.

I found a way to align it the way I want, but it has a bunch of `\,` and negative spaces that seem unnatural and are hard to align. Is there a better way to align this the way I want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Bad: $$
\begin{aligned}
    A(x) &= a_0 +& a_1 x + a_2 x^2 +& a_3 x^3 + a_4 x^4 + \cdots \\
x\, A(x) &=      & a_0 x + a_1 x^2 +& a_2 x^3 + a_3 x^4 + \cdots \\
x^3 A(x) &=      &                  & a_0 x^3 + a_1 x^4 + \cdots
\end{aligned}
$$

Good: $$
\begin{aligned}
    A(x) &= a_0 \,+&\negmedspace\negmedspace\!\! a_1 x + a_2 x^2 \,+&\, a_3 x^3 + a_4 x^4 + \cdots \\
x\, A(x) &=        &\negmedspace\negmedspace\!\! a_0 x + a_1 x^2 \,+&\, a_2 x^3 + a_3 x^4 + \cdots \\
x^3 A(x) &=        &                                                &\, a_0 x^3 + a_1 x^4 + \cdots
\end{aligned}
$$

\end{document}
```

The above code gives this result in TeXworks (I am using the pdfLatex setting):

[image: the above code rendered in Latex]

I found [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29612/62608), but I don't want any leading plus signs, as I am only omitting leading terms.

Comment: Don't use `$$...$$` in LaTeX.

Comment: See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative is to use an array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\arraycolsep=0pt
\[
\begin{array}{rlll}
 A(x) &= a_0 +\null& a_1 x + a_2 x^2 +\null& a_3 x^3 + a_4 x^4 + \cdots \\
 x\, A(x) &=      & a_0 x + a_1 x^2 +\null& a_2 x^3 + a_3 x^4 + \cdots \\
 x^3 A(x) &=      &                  & a_0 x^3 + a_1 x^4 + \cdots
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: array]

Comment: The spacing in front of several `+` symbols isn't quite right.

Comment: The spacing in front of the + symbols is the normal math spacing.  The spacing after some of the + symbols is contolled by \arraycolsep.

Comment: In the first row, the space before the first and third `+` symbols isn't the same as right after them. Same for the spacing around the second `+` symbol in the second row.

Comment: Interesting, it seems that binary + and unary + are given different spacings.  The solution is to turn the unary + into binary +.  I will correct.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a simple `align*` environment along with some `\hphantom` statements in rows 2 and 3 to indicate the amounts of horizontal whitespace that need to be inserted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A(x) &= a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + a_4 x^4 + \cdots \\
x\, A(x) &= \hphantom{a_0 +{}}  a_0 x + a_1 x^2 + a_2 x^3 + a_3 x^4 + \cdots \\
x^3 A(x) &= \hphantom{a_0 +a_0 x + a_1 x^2+{}}a_0 x^3 + a_1 x^4 + \cdots
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can exploit the fact that the coefficients occupy the same space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    A(x) ={}&& a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + a_4 x^4 + \cdots \\
x\, A(x) ={}&&       a_0 x + a_1 x^2 + a_2 x^3 + a_3 x^4 + \cdots \\
x^3 A(x) ={}&&                         a_0 x^3 + a_1 x^4 + \cdots
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

With `={}` we ensure correct spacing after the equals sign; then we jump over the left aligned column to be in the right aligned one.

[image]