# change space between tabs, align environment

Tags: spacing, align

I have a problem formatting a few equations the right way. I have equations with 5 variables which should be displayed among themselves. I tried it with the align environment  and ended up using a lot of tabs. Is there a prettier solution? I guess reducing the space between the tabs would help a bit.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
200 &x_R + &150x_C& + &200x_M& + &100 x_T& + &100x_L& &\le& 250000 \\
150 &x_R+ &100x_C& + &100x_M& + &100x_T& &&&\le& 5000000 \\
4 &x_R + &4x_C&  + &4x_M& + &4x_T& &&&\le& 20 000 \\
15 &x_R + &10x_C& + &10x_M& + &15x_T& + &5x_L& &\le& 129600 \\
2 &x_R + &1x_C& + &1.5x_M& + &1.5x_T& + &1x_L& &\le& 129600 \\ 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}    
\begin{document}

\[ \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
  \begin{array}{*{4}{r<{{}}}l}
    -4 u_1 + & 2u_2 - & 3u_3 + & 4 u_4\le & \num{9} \\
    -3 u_1+ & 1u_2 + & 4u_3 + & 5u_4\le & \num{4} \\
    \multicolumn{4}{r}{( u_1,\, u_2,\, u_3, \,u_4\ge{}} & 0)\\
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does [Aligning polynomial terms](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29612) help?

Comment: I updated my answer to the linked question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29612 with the example you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest code is obtained with a suitable `array` environment, right-aligned for the left hand side, left aligned for the right hand side (you may change that if you prefer). Columns begin with the coefficients of the unknowns. If an equation is missing some unknown, end up the previous ‘block `coefficient+unknown`’ with `\hphantom{{}+{}}`. I load the `siunitx` package to properly format the numbers in the r.h.s.. As for the condition on the unknowns, you may align on the `≥` sign,  but I think semantically it's independent of the inequations, so I would align them by the left. Both solutions are displayed:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array, mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\[ \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
  \begin{array}{*{5}{r<{{}}}l}
    200 x_R + & 150x_C + & 200x_M + & 100 x_T + & 100x_L\le & \num{250000} \\
    150 x_R+ & 100x_C + & 100x_M + & 100x_T\hphantom{{}+{}} & \le & \num{5000000} \\
    4 x_R + & 4x_C + & 4x_M + & 4x_T\hphantom{{}+{}} & \le & \num{20 000} \\
    15 x_R + & 10x_C + & 10x_M + & 15x_T + & 5x_L \le & \num{129600} \\
    2x_R + & 1x_C + & 1.5x_M + & 1.5x_T + & 1x_L\le & \num{129600}\\[1ex]
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{( x_R,\, x_C,\, x_M, \,x_T, \,x_L\ge 0)} \\
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{( x_R,\, x_C,\, x_M, \,x_T, \,x_L\ge{}} & 0)\\
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks pretty good. I just don't want the brace on the left-side. For what exactly do I need  siunitx? Is it possible to put a last line `x_R, x_C, ... x_T \ge 0` which ignores the tabbing for the variables but greaterequals?

Comment: @user3667018 `siunitx` provides the `\num` command which Bernard has used to pretty-print the numbers on the right hand side. Note that the numbers are grouped in groups of three digits.

Comment: `siunitx` is here only for the formatting of the big numbers on the r.h.s., through the `\num` command. The `numprint` package has a similar command. As for the conditions in a further line, it's easy, but semantically, I would suggest aligning on the left. See my updated answer, where both ways are shown.

Comment: I tried todo it without the `siunitx` package and deleted the `\num` statements. Now I get an error in the following line:  `\begin{array}{*{2}{r<{{}}}l}`.

Comment: The line should be `begin{array}{*{5}{r<{{}}}l}`. Without some formatting the r.h.s. numbers will not be very readable. If you do not want a package for that, my suggestion is to do it by hand: `5\,000\,000`  for instance